# How to detect if a file has changed in a model save function

Tags: python, django, models

When updating a record with an existing file if the file has changed I need to remove the old file from the S3 bucket.

How in Django can I detect if a file has changed?

This is what I have tried (not tested) but does Django have some magic build in for this?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    existing_file = Asset.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
    if existing_file != self.file:
        # remove from s3 before saving the new file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` and `!=` would only compare primary keys of the model instances (look at the `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` methods [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L483)).

One way to compare all the fields of the model instances is to call [model_to_dict()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L112) on both:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

if model_to_dict(existing_file) != model_to_dict(self.file):
```

You can also specify `fields` and `exclude` arguments to control what fields to dump to dictionary, in your case, basically what fields to compare.

Hope that helps.